# Struct format in python3 for int16, char[][12] and char[100]

Tags: python-3.x, struct

I'm working on the tcp/ip protocol and have to pack and unpack the data for sending and receiving, to pack and unpack I need to have the struct format, The requirement is the C struct equivalant python struct, I have refered the struct documentation and has the confusion for below code..

```
int16
char[][12]
char[100]
```

I have created like below in python, is it correct? if not what is correct method for int16, char[][12],char[100]

```
struct.Struct('<h12s100s')
```

Comment: `struct` only handles fixed-sized data - `char[][12]` could be any multiple of 12 bytes in length.  Possibly that int at the start tells you the number of times the `char[12]` is repeated, and could be used to dynamically generate a struct format string.

Comment: Is there anyother way?, i have changed if int is 2 then char[][12] as 12s12s still has issue